# How to solve a gridworld problem using dp with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, dynamic-programming, maze, gridworld

I am trying to solve a GridWorld problem using numpy. This consists of a 3x3 maze with terminal states at (3,2) and (3,3) and rewards of -1 and +1 respectively. Through dynamic programming, I want to determine the value of each of the states. The robot can move in all directions with a probability of 0.8 of taking the desired action and a probability of 0.1 of moving to its right or left respectively.

I have some doubts because we are given three trials that are considered for the experiment:

Trace 1
<(1,1), 0> → E → <(1,2), 0> → E → <(1,3), 0> → S → <(2,3), 0> → S → <(3,3), 1>

Trace 2:
<(1,1), 0> → E → <(1,2), 0> → E → <(2,2), 0> → N → <(1,2), 0> → E → <(1,3), 0> → S → <(2,3), 0> → S → <(3,3), 1>

Trace 3:
<(1,1), 0> → E → <(2,1), 0> → N → <(1,1), 0> → E → <(1,2), 0> → E → <(1,3), 0> → S → <(2,3), 0> → S → <(3,3), 1>

I'm not sure if these trials are relevant for the code implementation. However, they have been useful for me to make a manual approximation of the state values using the Bellman formula.

I have created the following code, but it gives me the final states below, which I think are not correct (at least the politics of movement seems right but is the value numbers what does not seem okay to me). I do not see what I am doing wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("darkgrid")

# Parameters defining the grid, final states, and possible actions in the environment:
dimension = 3  # Dimension of our 3x3 grid
finalStates = [[2, 1], [2, 2]]  # Final states
actions = [[-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]]  # Actions: move up, down, right, left

# Parameters for calculating the value function:
gamma = 0.9  # Discount factor
rewardValue = 0  # Reward for normal movement
numIterations = 1000  # Number of algorithm iterations

# Function that returns the next state and reward when taking an action from a state
def calculateStateReward(initialState, action):
    # If our initial state is a final state, there is no change or reward
    if initialState in finalStates:
        return initialState, 0

    # If it moves, apply the reward
    reward = rewardValue
    # Calculate the new state
    finalState = np.array(initialState) + np.array(action)
    
    if -1 in finalState or 3 in finalState:  # If we go out of the maze, stay in the initial state
        finalState = initialState
        
    # Assign rewards for final states
    if (finalState == np.array([2, 1])).all():    # After moving, check if the final state is among the final states and return the associated reward.
        return finalState, -1
  
    if (finalState == np.array([2, 2])).all():    
        return finalState, +1

    return finalState, reward

# Initialize cell values
cellValues = np.zeros((dimension, dimension))
cellValues[2, 1] = -1  # Terminal state (3,2)
cellValues[2, 2] = 1  # Terminal state (3,3)

states = [[i, j] for i in range(dimension) for j in range(dimension)]  # Positions in the grid

deltas = []
# Execute the value iteration
for iteration in range(numIterations):
    
    copyCellValues = np.copy(cellValues)
    deltaState = []
    
    for state in states:
        
        if state in finalStates:  # Skip final states
            continue
        
        weightedRewards = 0
        
        # Calculate the expected value using the Bellman equation
        for action in actions:
            
            # Calculate the expected value for the desired action
            finalState, reward = calculateStateReward(state, action)
            
            if -1 in finalState or 3 in finalState:
                continue
            
            desiredValue = 0.8 * (reward + gamma * copyCellValues[finalState[0], finalState[1]])
            
            # Calculate the expected value for the action to the left of the agent
            leftAction = [-action[1], action[0]]
            leftState, leftReward = calculateStateReward(state, leftAction)
            
            if -1 in leftState or 3 in leftState:
                continue
            
            leftValue = 0.1 * (leftReward + gamma * copyCellValues[leftState[0], leftState[1]])
            
            # Calculate the expected value for the action to the right of the agent
            rightAction = [action[1], -action[0]]
            rightState, rightReward = calculateStateReward(state, rightAction)
            
            if -1 in rightState or 3 in rightState:
                continue
            
            rightValue = 0.1 * (rightReward + gamma * copyCellValues[rightState[0], rightState[1]])
            
            # Combine the values with probabilities
            weightedRewards += desiredValue + leftValue + rightValue
            
        deltaState.append(np.abs(copyCellValues[state[0], state[1]] - weightedRewards))
        copyCellValues[state[0], state[1]] = weightedRewards
        
    deltas.append(deltaState)
    cellValues = copyCellValues
    
    if iteration in [0, 1, 2, 9, 99, numIterations - 1]:
        print("Iteration {}".format(iteration + 1))
        print(cellValues)


Iteration 1
[[ 0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.   -1.9   0.19]
 [-1.9  -1.    1.  ]]
Iteration 2
[[ 0.     -1.71   -1.368 ]
 [-3.42   -6.346  -4.8716]
 [-8.398  -1.      1.    ]]
Iteration 3
[[ -4.617    -12.6369   -18.22005 ]
 [-20.5029   -36.11026  -51.381719]
 [-35.46901   -1.         1.      ]]
Iteration 10
[[-3.48617826e+06 -1.03834636e+07 -2.09657485e+07]
 [-8.88495296e+06 -2.34290181e+07 -4.60427294e+07]
 [-1.09129728e+07 -1.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]
Iteration 100
[[-2.53277516e+81 -7.59166758e+81 -1.53767710e+82]
 [-6.44869368e+81 -1.71037521e+82 -3.36998977e+82]
 [-7.89775648e+81 -1.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]
Iteration 1000
[[-inf -inf -inf]
 [-inf -inf -inf]
 [-inf  -1.   1.]]
```

Comment: Some possible issues: 1) Would the "desired" movement be down, i.e. not up ; 2) The `for action in actions` iterates through all direction choices from a state. You do not check whether the move was illegal (went out of bounds), this move occured with 80% weight whether or not it was right or left, and you additionally check left/right from the ending state here ... 3) you copy the original cellValues array at the beginning of every iteration, the copied arrays are modified and discarded, you only keep the final iteration worth of values

Comment: @ChaseLP , made some changes in my code but still resulting in wrong values...